# How to connect to a remote Git repository with IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, remote-server

Having issues trying to get my IntelliJ-Idea to connect to a remote server containing the git repos.  My computer is running OpenSuse 15.1 with Ultimate 2019.1

The following is what I get when logged into the remote server:

```
mschumacher@omares-dev3 ~/src/xxx $ git remote show origin
Password: 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@omares-git.xxx.com:/var/git/Repo.git
  Push  URL: git@omares-git.xxx.com:/var/git/Repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
```

I've done many attempts with no luck in getting it connected.  I've created a new project and ?enabled? VCS with Git.  I have put in "omares-git.xxx.com" - in addition, I found a link for a web view of the repositories that are available. The path for the url is 'omares-git.xxx.com/git' - but under that has a "projects".

I've located the actual location on the server...

```
mschumacher@omares-repos:/var/git> hostname -i
10.0.33.58
mschumacher@omares-repos:/var/git> ls
git-notifier-config.yml  Repo.git
```

Please note I've changed a few things of the output to keep things safe.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean under "connect to a remote repo". IntelliJ relies on the command-line git, and so to push/pull you need to have correct remote URL set-up (VCS - Git - Remotes... can help), and SSH-keys configured (if you use them).

Comment: "Remote" is just my definition - guess it really is just a server.  With my current project, I have Enable VCS for GIT - with the above stuff (not for sure if enough) but I'm trying to add a Remote and have to enter a URL - but with what I've tried so far just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, newbie me finally figured it out. After enabling the project to GIT, I was able to get to the VCS -> Git -> Remotes, added one using the full "Push" url above. Now I'm further with the way I want to use IntelliJ

Comment: how to do that 'enabling the project to GIT'?

Answer (score 0):

sync your code via `sftp` you can deploy the changes as soon as you save with this in intellij idea ultimate [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html)